# Change value of Objectkey at indexpath

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have an NSMUTABLEARRAY with many objects. I want to change the value of and object inside indexkey of that mutable.

Here is how i log the value i want to change

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[_arrayProdsCarrito objectAtIndex:_intIndexProductoEnArray] objectForKey:@"price"]);
```

Comment: How did you try to edit it?

Comment: I dont know that why ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mutable so just change it:

```
_arrayProdsCarrito[_intIndexProductoEnArray][@"price"] = 99.99;
```